# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a little program to analyze some data I have and this code, which worked yesterday, is no longer working.
For the life of me, I can't tell why.  To my eye, everything is as it should be.  I've tried re-syncing the folder on my computer with my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/dedSea/WeatherProgram) and still was receiving the same error.  Maybe a second pair of eyes could help me out?

The text file being read from can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/8Q6YF1Bk).

Here are the methods referred to by the stack trace:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    FileManagementMethods fmm = new FileManagementMethods();
    fmm.runProgram();

}
```

```
void runProgram() throws IOException{
    boolean doesFileExist = doesFileExist();
    if(doesFileExist){
        int numLines = getNumberOfLines();
        String[] linesFromFile = getLines(numLines);
        WeatherAnalysisMethods wam = new WeatherAnalysisMethods();
        wam.parseFileAverageTemp(linesFromFile);
        wam.parseFileAverageHumidity(linesFromFile);
        wam.predictNextTemperature(linesFromFile);
    } else{
        try {
            throw new IOException("Could not find log.txt in default directory");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
void parseFileAverageHumidity(String[] linesFromFile) throws IOException{
    int[] humiditiesFromFile = new int[linesFromFile.length];
    humiditiesFromFile = getHumiditiesFromFile(linesFromFile.length);
    int averageFromFile = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < humiditiesFromFile.length; i++){
        averageFromFile += humiditiesFromFile[i];
    }
    averageFromFile = averageFromFile / humiditiesFromFile.length;
    String outString = "Average humidity for whole file = " + averageFromFile;
    FileManagementMethods fmm = new FileManagementMethods();
    fmm.saveAnalyzedData(outString);
}
```

```
int[] getHumiditiesFromFile(int numLines){
    int[] humiditiesFromFile = new int[numLines];
    FileManagementMethods fmm = new FileManagementMethods();
    String[] lines = fmm.getLines(numLines);
    int i = 0;
    while(1 < numLines){
        String[] lineDivides = lines[i].split(",");
        String tempString = lineDivides[4]; 
        humiditiesFromFile[i] = Integer.parseInt(tempString);
        i++;
    }
    return humiditiesFromFile;
}
```

Line 51:

```
String tempString = lineDivides[4];
```

And here is the **stack trace**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
at org.weatheralert.analysis.WeatherAnalysisMethods.getHumiditiesFromFile(WeatherAnalysisMethods.java:51)
at org.weatheralert.analysis.WeatherAnalysisMethods.parseFileAverageHumidity(WeatherAnalysisMethods.java:22)
at org.weatheralert.analysis.FileManagementMethods.runProgram(FileManagementMethods.java:22)
at org.weatheralert.analysis.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

If you guys need more information, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: update your answer to say what line is WeatherAnalysisMethods.java:51

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here, inside your `getHumiditiesFromFile` method:

```
while(1 < numLines){
```

It should be

```
while (i < numLines){
```

Since inside this loop you're calling `humiditiesFromFile[i]`.

---

As Foo Bar User noted in comment, the error may be here:

```
String tempString = lineDivides[4];
```

It would be better to make sure there are at least 4 items in that array.

Besides that, the error noted in the section above (assuming it's not a typo) could also throw this Exception for being in an infinite loop.

Comment: more likely to be here lineDivides[4]

Comment: @FooBarUser note that since we don't know which line is number 51 from `WeatherAnalysisMethods`, we can't be sure. Also, note that OP has `humiditiesFromFile[i]` inside the `while`.

Comment: yeah thats a better answer, actualy he should mention where is line 51

Comment: The correct line is listed by Foo Bar User.  My apologies for not listing that.
http://pastebin.com/8Q6YF1Bk
Click here for the file that contains the data being read

Comment: Even after changing the code to what Luiggi suggested, I'm still getting the exact thing in the stack trace.  The "1" there was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You've hardcoded a `4` here without checking to see if it exists:

```
String tempString = lineDivides[4];
```

You will need to do some data validation beforehand.  You're assuming that the line you read has at least three commas.  Either change the code to check, or validate the file.

Comment: I commented above with the link to the pastebin page holding the data being read.

Comment: @NickMedovich Haha, I'm not going to validate a hundred lines of data for you.  Sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, it was a silly issue....  JSoup had a couple bad connections and didn't save some of the data I needed it to save.  So it didn't recognize some of the lines of data.
Once I fixed the actual data, it runs without issue again.
I apologize for wasting your time.